# How to get the number of comments and likes of a fb post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to get the number of likes and comments of a fb page using Js SDK. Latest version of Fb graph doesn't allow to use old methods. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: please add what you have tried (research, code, debug info, ...) - did you already check out the api reference?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the documentation for the [feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/page/feed) edge on the graph API? This call:

```
<PAGE_ID>/feed?fields=likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)
```

Will get the likes and comments of a pages posts, including the total_count of each per post.